# MudBlazor: MudTablePager change language of 'Rows per Page'

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

Is there a possibility to change this text:

[image: MudTablePager]

to something like 'Elemente pro Seite' for example?

I changed the InfoFormat but i can't find an option to change the left side text?

Code:

```
<PagerContent>
    <MudTablePager InfoFormat="@infoFormat"/>
</PagerContent>

@code {
      private string infoFormat = "{first_item}-{last_item} von {all_items}";
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a property `RowsPerPageString`:

```
<MudTablePager PageSizeOptions="new int[] { 20, 50}" RowsPerPageString="your-own-text" />
```